# Implementing a property using the double asterisk (**)

Tags: python, properties

Following http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property, I'm familiar with the following method of implementing a property in Python:

```
class Celsius(object):
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
```

I'm now reading some code in which the double asterisk (`**`) is used in defining the property. If I adapt it to my own example, it seems to be like this:

```
class Celsius(object):
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def temperature():
        def fget(self):
            print("Getting value")
            return self._temperature
        def fset(self, value):
            if value < -273:
                raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
            print("Setting value")
            self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(**temperature())
```

However, if I try to run this code and instantiate a class through `c = Celsius()`, I get

```
TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

I understand that `fget` and `fset` are keyword arguments of `property`, so I would expect what comes out of `**temperature()` to be something like `fget=fget, fset=fset`, but I am not sure what is going wrong here or how to dissect it further. Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing "comes out" of `temperature()`. There's no `return`. You're defining `fget` and `fset` as local functions within `temperature`, but they don't "come out" unless you `return` them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return` the nested functions and then unpack them according from the function call:

```
class Celsius(object):
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def temperature():
        ...
        return fget, fset

    temperature = property(*temperature())
```

If you insist on using `**`, then you'll be returning a mapping/dictionary from your function which will then be *unpacked* as keyword arguments.

```
def temperature():
    ...
    return {'fget': fget, 'fset': fset}

temperature = property(**temperature())
```

Comment: Since the naming of the `fget` and `fset` functions adheres to the keyword arguments of `property`, in the second case one can also `return locals()` instead of `return {'fget': fget, 'fset': fset}` as mentioned in my 'self-answer'.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the `temperature()` call returns `None`, which you then attempt to unpack as if it were a dictionary, using `**`. So to get that code working you need to return an appropriate dictionary containing the setter & getter methods.

I prefer Moses' solution, but you *could* pass the methods with a dict instead of a tuple if you really want. Eg,

```
class Celsius(object):
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self._temperature = temperature

    def temperature():
        def fget(self):
            print("Getting value")
            return self._temperature
        def fset(self, value):
            if value < -273:
                raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
            print("Setting value")
            self._temperature = value
        return {'fget': fget, 'fset': fset}

    temperature = property(**temperature())

# Test
a = Celsius()
a.temperature = 20
print(a.temperature)
```

**output**

```
Setting value
Getting value
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I had missed the `return` statement in the function definition of `temperature`. The original code actually contains the line

```
return locals()
```

Adding this line makes the property work as intended.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, that works, but I really don't like fiddling with `locals()`, even when you're only reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

The `temperature` method you are defining does not have a return statement, so it implicitly returns `None`, this the `...,not NoneType` in your error message. The method does have two sub-methods,  but that does not cause it to return them in any form, I think you are missing a line such as ( untested ):

```
return { "fget": fget, "fset": fset }
```

You could also use a list and a single `*`.

That being said, it's a best practice to avoid `*` and `**` magic, there's also a [pylint rule](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0142) to discourage it.